# std::filesystem::create_directory permissions differes from reality

Tags: c++, gcc, std-filesystem

At cpp reference ([std::filesystem::create_directory](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/create_directory)) - we can see the follow descriptrion:

> 1. Creates the directory p as if by POSIX mkdir() with a second
>    argument of static_cast(**std::filesystem::perms::all**) (the parent
>    directory must already exist). If the function fails because p
>    resolves to an existing directory, no error is reported. Otherwise on
>    failure an error is reported.

`std::filesystem::perms::all` - implies all permissions ie `777`.

But when I created a directory (by `std::filesystem::create_directory`) in /tmp on my ubuntu 20.4 - this directory only have drwxrwxr-x (`775` in numeric format)

Why this happens?

PS

I use gcc 10.3

Comment: You probably want to read about `umask`: [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/umask.2.html) and [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/umask.1p.html).  If you type `umask` at a command prompt I'm guessing the output is something like `0002` in your case?